# Symfony2 form login providers in_memory, login fail

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication

This is my configuration:

#### #security.yml

```
security:

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:
                    password: user
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                admin:
                    password: admin
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        anonymous: ~
        access_denied_url: backoffice_access_denied

        form_login:
            login_path: /backoffice/login
            check_path: /backoffice/login_check

        logout:
            path:   /backoffice/logout
            target: /backoffice

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

access_control:
    - { path: ^/backoffice/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/backoffice, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

#### #routing.yml

```
backoffice_logout:
    path: /backoffice/logout

backoffice_login_check:
    path: /backoffice/login_check
```

Obviously I have a controller for the route /backoffice/login that renders the login form with the right input name (_username, _password).

when I compile the form if I enter the wrong username and password data I rightly appears bad credential, but if I enter the correct data I'm redirected back to the login page as an anonymous user.

Some app/logs...

```
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] request.INFO: Matched route "backoffice_login_check". {"route_parameters":{"_route":"backoffice_login_check"},"request_uri":"http://DOMAIN/backoffice/login_check"} []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"admin"} []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.request". [] []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest" was not called for event "kernel.request". [] []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_secured_area"} []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] request.INFO: Matched route "backoffice_index_lead". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"XXX\\AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::leadAction","_route":"backoffice_index_lead"},"request_uri":"http://DOMAIN/backoffice/lead"} []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at /site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:70)"} []
[2016-03-02 10:39:54] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
```

How you can see at line 2 login was done successfully but when the controller redirect to the secured are i obtain access denied (line 8)

Where am I wrong?
Thank you.

## EDIT:

This is my config.yml

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        packages:
            v_assets:
                version: %app.assets_version%
                version_format:  "assets/%%2$s/%%1$s"
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
```

## EDIT2:

My symfony project running on **NGNIX/HHVM**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

throws to HHVM bucket and install php!

Comment: the solution was change from hhvm to php!Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your change session options:

```
session: ~
```

to:

```
session:
   handler_id:  ~
```

Comment: nope.

i added the provider: in_memory but obtain the same error.

Comment: so it could be a session issue, try to change 
session: ~
to 
session:
    handler_id:  ~

Comment: I edit my question and added my config.yml.
the session has the handler_id param

Comment: In your log, after the security token get stored you should see something like this: `Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_secured_area"} []`. but you don't have it, so probably its a session issue

Comment: try to change the session option to `session: ~`

Comment: i tried also with and without handler_id but no work.

Comment: delete all your cookies and try again